# Matrix or loops or any ideas for help me

Tags: matrix, list-manipulation, procedural-programming

I have input data as below:

```
Fk := {{F0}, {F1}, {F2}, {F3}, {F4}, {F5}, {F6}}

\[Gamma]k := {{\[Gamma]0}, {\[Gamma]1}, {\[Gamma]2}, {\[Gamma]3}, {\\[Gamma]4}, {\[Gamma]5}, {\[Gamma]6}}

\[Phi]kp1 := {{\[Phi]k1}, {\[Phi]k2}, {\[Phi]k3}, {\[Phi]k4}, \{\[Phi]k5}, {\[Phi]k6}, {\[Phi]k7}}
```

And have to calculate this formula:

```
 Qk=Fk*Cos[[Phi]kp1]/Sin[[Gamma]k]
```

And my question: How can we calculate the Qk without input FK, [Gama]k, [Phi]kp1 looking like

```
   Fk := {{F0}, {F1}, {F2}, {F3}, {F4}, {F5}, {F6}},...
```

I mean how we can put only k= number such as 6 and get the result Qk=[Q1,Q2...].

### K=6, Function Fk Function [Gama]k Function [Phi]kp1 Function Qk=Fk*Cos[[Phi]kp1]/Sin[[Gamma]k] And get the results: Qk=[Q1,Q2...]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using Array -- hence

```
k = 6;
ff = Array[f, k];
gam = Array[g, k];
phi = Array[p, k];
```

Then your calculation is:

```
q = ff*Cos[phi]/Sin[gam]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It is exactly what I need.